# adding an attribute to form field without overwriting defaults in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I need to add an attribute to a form field in symfony.
I do it like this in my form type:

```
->add('myfield','text',array('attr'=>array('myattrib'=>"test")))
```

But this overwrites defult `attributes` of that field (e.g. classes)

How can I add an attribute to a field without overwriting other attributes?

Thanks

Comment: where do you add other attributes to the field?

Comment: @NawfalSerrar: That is the point! I don't! I just want to keep defaults and add one more to them.

Comment: give me an example of attributes which is deleted after you add your attr? i never had this problem

Answer (score 0):

you can add it using twig if you wanna just to keep your php code clear, here is an exemple :

```
{{ form_row(form.Address,{
                'attr':{
                    'class':'form-control',
                    'min-length':'4',
                    'required':'true',
                }
            }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form add the attribute like this :

```
->add('myfield','text',array('attr'=>array('myattrib'=>"test"),'mapped'=>false))
```

Otherwise you can add it in your twig view when rendering you form with form_row() just add the input like normale html and get int in your action after posting like this :

```
$posted_value = $this->get('request')->request->get('Name attribute of your input')
```